# Copying formulas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing many sheets, most of which have formulas.

I have managed to copy most of the sheets (with formulas) into a new Excel file. To copy the sheets I used Copy and Paste Special, selecting all. This works in most cases.

I have one problem sheet from which I am unable to copy the formulas over to my new file.

Firstly by using Paste Special I got `#REF` in all of the cells. I then used Copy, Paste Values, then copy again and paste formulas. The two sheets match but the formulas don't copy over.

If I paste formulas, the `#REF` comes up in the boxes.

Answer (score 3):

The copied formulas probably have references to other sheets of the same file. They contain references like this: `mysheet!A5`

If you copy them to a new file, you have to name the sheets with the exact name (`mysheet` in my example), so the copied formulas will work inside the new file.

It could be simpler to just copy the whole file and give it a different name, then delete the parts you don't want.

Comment: I like the idea of copying the file and deleting the parts that she doesn't need. This is how many people tend to do it.